# How to delete the hidden files in windows /

Tags: windows-7

Is it safe to delete all the administrative shares or the hidden files/shares when they appear? For whatever reason they appeared everywhere in the folders suddenly all together.

Comment: It's not safe to delete ALL hidden files when they appear EVERYWHERE, because they probably appear for some reason. Can you specify what files you mean? Can you add some example?

Comment: They may have appeared because you might have clicked Show All Hidden Files?

Comment: That depends entirely on what an "administrative share" is. Unless you know, it's not safe.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leaving them, don't delete something you're not sure about (there's exceptions here, like viruses flagged by your AV). If your antivirus put them there, it must have done for a reason. Also, I suggest leaving the 'view hidden folders' off unless you really need it, if you have it on.

If you don't mind me asking, what antivirus do you have?